# How can I create an app with the behavior of the default Android "timer" app?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create an app that allows the user to set a timer. When they start the timer, they see a screen with a countdown. Simultaneously, a notification appears in the system tray (the top bar). This notification contains the current state of the countdown. If the app is minimized and the user taps that notification, they return to the countdown screen in the app.

I'm trying to do this with a foreground Service, and then implementing the notification like so:

```java
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    notificationIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

The problem is, this seems to restart the activity, not resume it (`onCreate` gets called again), so the timer appears zeroed out in the activity. Is there a way around this?

Comment: "so the timer appears zeroed out in the activity" -- have the activity get the remaining time from the same source that is updating the notification. Somewhere, you have a single source of truth of the remaining time. You are using that to update the `Notification`, and you should be using that to update the activity, whether it is the existing instance or some new one. In terms of your "restart the activity" part, you might try [one of the documented patterns](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation).

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you saying I should just accept that the Activity will be re-Created, but that I should just pass in the remaining time when that happens?

Comment: "Are you saying I should just accept that the Activity will be re-Created" -- well, the user can always exit the activity via system BACK navigation, in which case the activity will be recreated. Plus, activities get recreated via configuration changes. You need to handle those cases. "that I should just pass in the remaining time when that happens?" -- your activity should be arranging to observe some reactive single source of truth for how much time is remaining, the same source of truth that you are using to update the notification.

Comment: In terms of avoiding the second activity instance... that is why I suggested perhaps following [one of the documented patterns](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation).